# How to install plugin in Craft 3

Tags: craft3

I've tried installing a plugin to my Craft 3 local installation. I ran this from the command line in my project root:

`composer require boboldehampsink/import` but, this error was returned

`craft/plugins/import/ does not exist and could not be created.`

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install a Craft 2.x plugin, which you can see, among other things, by looking at its composer.json. Craft 3 plugins will always have a `"extra` property with a `"handle"` defined.

```
"extra": {
    "handle": "plugin-handle",
}
```

The currently latest release of the Import plugin is v0.8.33, and is not compatible with Craft 3:
https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/blob/0.8.33/composer.json

Until the plugin store goes live, most plugin developers note their compatible plugins in this list:
https://github.com/craftcms/plugins

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could use the [craft3 branch](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/tree/craft3), but looks like that's not going to work.

Comment: Craft 3 alpha and beta releases had a couple of breaking changes so far, and it looks like that branch didn’t get updated for months.